# writing a dictionary function

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a function that takes such a dictionary as the first argument and an integer as the second argument and returns the list of keys all of whose values are bigger than the second argument. I'm thinking of building it using a for loop to be much simpler.

Comment: What language? What do you mean by "such a dictionary"? Is this homework? (My best guess: Python; it's homework; "such a dictionary" refers back to an earlier part of what you were asked to do.) If it's Python: do you know about list comprehensions? You can do this much more neatly without a `for` loop.

Comment: What's the question? And once you have a question, we'll need to know what language you are writing this in.

Comment: "Show me teh codez!" -- will this ever end?

Comment: yes it is a python homework.. sorry for not saying what language i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which language do you use? what kind of dictionary do you use?

If Python, use the following:

`[ x for x, y in mydict.items() if y > 42 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

KeysOverX() - You can port it if you want as we don't know the language you want :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DictionaryQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string [] args ) {
            // Define dictionary
            Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dict.Add( 1, "lorum" );
            dict.Add( 2, "ipsum" );
            dict.Add( 3, "this" );
            dict.Add( 4, "is" );
            dict.Add( 5, "a" );
            dict.Add( 6, "test" );

            // Define
            int startKey = 4;

            var results = KeysOverX( dict, startKey );

            foreach ( int k in results ) {
                Console.WriteLine( k );
            }
        }

        static IList<int> KeysOverX( Dictionary<int, string> dictionary, int lowestKey ) {
            return (from item in dictionary
                    where item.Key > lowestKey
                    select item.Key).ToList<int>();
        }
    }
}
```